# How to clear the score when updating new score using clearRect?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, draw

I am creating a snake game using JavaScript and I am at the point where I can increment the snake upon eating the food, and have the "Score: 0" showing up but when the score updates it keeps the zero being drawn on top of the updated score.

I have used the clearRect and cleartext methods above the score being drawn and under it.

I have created the drawScore in it's own function and called that function with the clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height) method

```
function drawEverything() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext('2d');            

    ctx.fillStyle = "#2a2a2a";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 50, gameCanvas.width, gameCanvas.height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 50, gameCanvas.width, gameCanvas.height);

    //draws snake
    for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = (i == 0) ? "red" : "white";
        ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y +4.66, pixel, pixel);

        ctx.strokeStyle = (i ==0) ? "white" : "black";
        ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y +4.66, pixel, pixel);
    }

    //draws apple
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(apple.x +7.5, apple.y +11, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    //old snake head
    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;


    //moves snake according to which direction the user initiates
    if (snakeDirection == "LEFT") snakeX -= pixel;
    if (snakeDirection == "UP") snakeY -= pixel;
    if (snakeDirection == "RIGHT") snakeX += pixel;
    if (snakeDirection == "DOWN") snakeY += pixel;

    if (snakeX == apple.x && snakeY == apple.y) {
        score++;
        apple = {
            x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) * pixel,
            y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 33 + 3.66) * pixel
        }
    } else {
        //remove the tail
        snake.pop();
    }

    //new head creation
    let newHead = {
        x: snakeX,
        y: snakeY
    }

    //creates the new head
    snake.unshift(newHead);

    //draws score
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.font = "30px arial";
        ctx.fillText(scoreText + score, 3 * pixel, 2.3 * pixel);

}
```

Here is a link to the code pen.

https://codepen.io/gjindo/pen/vwEjoy

Comment: You already seem to know the solution -- `clearRect` -- but you're not using it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yeah however when I am using it, the score disappears completely. I am wondering if I am missing something, maybe the position in which where the clearRect goes?

Comment: If it's causing the text to disappear you're probably using it *after* drawing the text -- you should clear the area first.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the solution ctx.clearRect("put the co-ordinates of the score here")

However, this will most likely just leave a blank square the colour of your canvas. 
To fix this, just draw the background and player again after using the clear rect.

This is a bit of a cheap way of doing it, but always worked for me.